# Why infinite animation not working on android in phonegap?

Tags: android, css, cordova, animation, phonegap-build

```
#btn
{
    border-radius:50%;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#ffcccc;
    display:block;
    outline:0;
    margin:25% auto;
    animation-name: shake;
    animation-duration:4s;
    animation:mymove infinite;
}
@keyframes shake {
    0%, 100% {transform: translateX(0);}
    10%, 30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {transform: translateX(-10px);}
    20%, 40%, 60%, 80% {transform: translateX(10px);}
}
```

This is my css file ,here i am adding animation like left<->current<->right.

This continuous animation working in ios,but android not working, If i remove the infinite animation then for 4s animation occurs in android.

What i did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the problem **Animation:mymove infinite;** instead of this use **animation-iteration-count:infinite;**

```
#btn
{
    border-radius:50%;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#ffcccc;
    display:block;
    outline:0;
    margin:25% auto;
    animation-name: shake;
    animation-duration:4s;
/*    animation:mymove infinite;*/
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```